# How do I buy from the Ubuntu One Music store through a web browser?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Where do I go when I'm using a non-Ubuntu computer and want to buy an album from the Ubuntu One Music store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu One team just released an online Ubuntu One Music store. You can browser and buy music from a web browser from https://one.ubuntu.com/music-store/.

The music store works regardless of the operating system. So, if you are on a non-Ubuntu computer, you can still use the online music store using a web browser.

[image: Ubuntu One music store]

[U1 blog post about online music store](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/09/11/ubuntu-one-music-store-now-on-the-web-and-on-your-mobile/)

Comment: For those who only discovered this recently and traveled across times to find this: the service was shut down in 2014, and that's why all links are dead.